# Issues using sumifs() in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

I'm trying to basically translate a formula from excel into VBA. I'm using the SUMIFS() command and I have it referring to columns in an already established table. This is what I have so far but I keep getting an object error.

```
Cells(2, 14).Value = 60 * Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs([Hours],[Operators], [@Operators], [Forging], [@Forging], [Operation], [@Operation], [Job No], [@[Job No]], [Time], ">" & [Time] - Time(1, 0, 0), [Time], "<" & [Time] + Time(1, 0, 0), [Workcenter], [@Workcenter])
```

I'm guessing that this isn't how you use SUMIFS() so how do you modify this so that it can function as it does in excel.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to exploit the power of the structured formula from VBA. Since you have a tested and working formula, you can let the cell evaluate it *as is* and then fix the value. for example:

```
With sheet1.Cells(2, 14)
  .Formula = "=SUMIFS([Hours],[Operators], [@Operators], [Forging], [@Forging], [Operation], [@Operation], [Job No], [@[Job No]], [Time], "">"" & [Time] - Time(1, 0, 0), [Time], ""<"" & [Time] + Time(1, 0, 0), [Workcenter], [@Workcenter])"
  .Value = .Value * 60
End with
```

only thing to be careful about here was: double-up any double-quotes inside the initial formula.

Comment: I ran this and got a type mismatch error on the .formula line